# Why gaussian assumption in GMM-HMM ASR?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science-model, speech-to-text

I am reading a book entitled *Speech and Language Processing* by Daniel Jurafsky and James.

For Acoustic vector, I would like to know why Gaussian assumption is made?

I searched over the internet and could not find the reason.

Answer (score 1):

One reason Gaussian distributions are assumed is that it simplifies modeling since a Gaussian distribution only has 2 parameters to estimate (i.e., mu and sigma) and the properties of the distribution are well understood.

Gaussian distributions are often a reasonable assumption for acoustic data since acoustic data can modeled as a sum of independent random variables. According to the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), the normalized sum of independent random variables  tends toward a Gaussian distribution.